# what is the proper way to implement the java Collection interface

Tags: java

I'm not sure what is the proper way to override all methods in `Collection<E>` interface.

I was asked to create a Class `HotDog implements Collection<E>`, thus i must override all methods it contains and I'm not sure how to do this since normally I believe the best solution would be to **inherit** from a class that **allready** implements  `Collection` interface.

The requirements would be to have the functionality of a **HotDog** Object for the purposes of  calculating  the full price of the HotDog depending on the amount of  ingredients  the hotdog  has, I believe the Collection functionality is for the ingredients in the hotdog.

Comment: There is no best way, it just depends on your requirements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three ways to create a new collection:

- *From scratch*. You implement all methods of the `Collection` interface.
- *Extending an existing class*, like you already mentioned. Java offers abstract classes for this purpose: `java.util.AbstractCollection` and various implementations for specific kinds of collection. These abstract classes allow you to focus on how the collections stores its elements instead of having to write all methods yourself.
- *Composition*. Your class is basically a wrapper for an existing collection class and redirects all its method calls (except for a few whose behavior you want to adapt) directly to the wrapped collection's methods.

Which method is best depends on your particular requirements.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. And how would one proceed to implement from *scratch*?

Comment: @estebanrincon Look at the JavaDoc for the `Collection` interface. First, you have to decide on a way to store the elements of the collection (e.g. an array or some kind of linked list), and then implement all methods of the interface.